# SignalR javascript in mvc razor app

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, signalr

I am trying to use signalR javascript to insert data from a mvc razor form to a database. Anyone have some good advice how to use properly? First time to work with SignalR. 
Here is the code I have and I need to enter the SignalR js code below the @RenderBody() line.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/knockout-2.0.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/json2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>My ASP.NET Web Page - @Page.Title</title>
        <link href="@Href("~/Styles/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="@Href("~/favicon.ico")" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="page">
            <div id="header">
                <p class="site-title">My ASP.NET Web Page</p>
                <div id="login">
                    @if (WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        <p>
                            Welcome <a href="@Href("~/Account/ChangePassword")" title="Change password">@WebSecurity.CurrentUserName</a>!
                            <a href="@Href("~/Account/Logout")">Logout</a>
                        </p>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="@Href("~/Account/Register")">Register</a></li>
                            <li><a href="@Href("~/Account/Login")">Login</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    }
                </div>
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li><a href="@Href("~/")">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Href("~/About")">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="main">
                <div id="content">
                    <h1>@Page.Title</h1>
                    @RenderBody()
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(function () {
                    var test = $.connection.SignalRHub();
                    </script>
                </div>
                <div id="footer">
                    &copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Web Page
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also I have class where I would like to enter the code to insert the data in a db. I need to use hub, I think that's the right way to do that, but anyone more experienced person with SignalR is more then welcome to give me advice.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using SignalR.Hubs;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for SignalRHub
/// </summary>
namespace SignalR
{
public class SignalRHub : Hub
{
    public SignalRHub(string message)
    {
        string test = "";
    }
    public void InsertData(string value)
    {

    }
    public void DeleteData(int id)
    {
    }
}
}
```

Thanks in advance, Laziale

Comment: I would assume the above code doesn't work (for a couple reasons)--are you asking how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the include for hubs. You can read more here https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/QuickStart-Hubs

Comment: It seems that I don't have that folder, "/signalr/hubs" in my root directory. Do I need to include that anyway? Thanks for helping me out

Comment: Check out the FAQ on how to do this with mvc: 
https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Faq

Comment: /signalr/hubs is a virtual path. it magically uses its voodoo to hook up an httpmodule somewhere and i think this responds to calls made to /signalr/hubs. a good way to check is to run your project and type /signalr/hubs into the browser. it should render some javascript to the screen. if you see the javascript you know its working and you can add the reference fine.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by reading this post:

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=780

It will walk you through how to setup SignalR and use it with ASP.NET MVC3. The article also includes fill source so you can dig through it. Here is the link to the code:

www.dotnetcurry.com/Uploads/mvc/MultiEditWithSignalR.zip

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can find the sample application here you want to do

http://www.amazedsaint.com/2011/11/introduction-ksigdo-knockout-signalr-to.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing the javascript include for hubs.

```
<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

For this to work you have to add a route for your hubs.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();

....
```

I don't know if you went ahead with SignalR, but it is defintely a great way of communicating to, between and from your clients .